# does celery docker container have to copy the same files from django container build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery, django-celery

**Here is tha raw question:**
i was wondering if i can run the command from celery container using another container data like django container as these containers are in the same network of containers on the server or i have to duplicate the data from django project to every container or is there another way?

**here is the question with explanation:**
i am new to this and i tried to make a docker composer file for a Django-rest project with celery and Rabitmq and PostgreSQL,
i followed bunch of tutorials and i manage to make it work as the celery container use a shared volume from Django to start the worker(also the beat celery container) see the picture for related code from docker compose:(edited part from one of suggestions i put the code instead of pic)

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./youdeal_djangopart
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    container_name: 'prod-djbackend'
    image: youdeal_djangopart-prod:0.63
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - '8000'
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - static-data:/static
      - media-data:/youdeal_djangopart/media
      - api_vol:/youdeal_djangopart
    environment:
      - "CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
  celeryworker:
    container_name: celeryworker
    image: celeryworker:0.51
    build:
      context: ./youdeal_djangopart
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.celery.prod
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/api_vol/
    links:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - api
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - "CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//"
volumes:
  api_vol:
```

now here is the problem when i want to deploy the project the server i am using (https://www.arvancloud.com/en) doesn't really allow shared volume  between containers and dont answer well in this regard, i was wondering if i can run the command from celery container using another container data like django container as these containers are in the same network of containers or i have to duplicate the data from django project to every container or is there another way?

i find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998821/docker-celery-and-code-in-different-containers/42009046#42009046)  and some other related topics but i couldn't make it work

Comment: I don't think Docker accepts PNG-format Compose files.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual text of the YAML file, instead of the screen shot?

Comment: You don't really make it clear what you're trying to do with shared volumes, but there are definitely a number of practical problems around trying to share files and I might try to restructure the data to avoid that.  A Celery worker will often use the same _code_ as a Django application, for example, and so they can use the same image and be configured to talk to the same external database container; volumes aren't part of that setup at all.

Comment: i am trying to start celery worker in the celery container using the data needed for it in the Django project container without coping all the Django project file in the celery worker container . i did this by sharing a volume in the docker compose file but this is not possible in the server(i can not share a volume but the containers are in the same network) so how can i start the celery worker using Django container files without coping them all over again ? hope this clears it thank you

Comment: Both containers share the same code (they are functionally using the same image) and the `depends_on:` constraints suggest you have both a RabbitMQ queue and some sort of relational database available.  What other data do you need to share?  What goes wrong if you just delete all of the `volumes:` from this file?

Comment: first thank you for your time, now , two containers connected to the same volume so this file works just fine with one source of files that is in api_vol and celery need those files to start and work; how ever if i dont have the api_vol available to celery container (as the case in my server) i want to use the files in django container that is in the same network with celery container and run celery worker without copying all the django files again? or my only option is to duplicate the project file in celery image as well to make it work